# Regular expression for pattern 123 X 123

Tags: regular-language

I would like to know the regular exp for the input patter 123 X 123.
Only integers allowed before and after X and also space before and after X.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try [1-9\s]+(X)[\s1-9]+

Comment: Hi, Alphabets are also executing. 11 X 11 is valid input and should execute but not 1a1 X 11.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9]\s*\s[0-9] is the regex expression for your given question.
[learn more at w3 about regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)